# How to implement upload component with one upload button in Vaadin?

Tags: java, upload, vaadin

I have the following class that implements the single Upload example

```
@Override
public void init() {
    Window mainWindow = new Window("Singleuploadclick Application");
    Label label = new Label("Hello Vaadin user");

    mainWindow.addComponent(label);

    status = new Label("Please select a file to upload");
    upload = new Upload(null, receiver);

    upload.setImmediate(true);
    upload.setButtonCaption("Select file");

    upload.addListener(new Upload.StartedListener() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void uploadStarted(StartedEvent event) {
            upload.setVisible(false);
            status.setValue("Uploading file \"" + event.getFilename() + "\"");
        }
    });

    upload.addListener(new Upload.ProgressListener() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void updateProgress(long readBytes, long contentLength) {
        }

    });

    upload.addListener(new Upload.SucceededListener() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void uploadSucceeded(SucceededEvent event) {
            status.setValue("Uploading file \"" + event.getFilename() + "\" succeeded");
        }
    });

    upload.addListener(new Upload.FailedListener() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void uploadFailed(FailedEvent event) {
            status.setValue("Uploading interrupted");
        }
    });

    upload.addListener(new Upload.FinishedListener() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void uploadFinished(FinishedEvent event) {
            upload.setVisible(true);
            upload.setCaption("Select another file");
        }
    });

    mainWindow.addComponent(status);
    mainWindow.addComponent(upload);            
    setMainWindow(mainWindow);
}
```

When running the application I get strange layout display of upload component.

[image]

So i need upload component just with one upload button, that why i used : upload.setImmediate(true);

Comment: it how it look see the screen: https://vaadin.com/documents/portlet_file_entry/10187/singleupload.png/6ff48247-965d-4917-86d9-5e37b12780ba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Button.setImmediate(true)` is used to start upload after file selection (without button click). But you still need to hide the button with CSS.

Quote from [Book of Vaadin 5.25 Upload](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.upload.html):

> You can also **hide the upload button with .v-upload .v-button {display: none} in theme**, have custom logic for starting the upload, and call startUpload() to start it. If the upload component has setImmediate(true) enabled, uploading starts immediately after choosing the file.

So you need to add this to your custom theme:

```
.v-upload .v-button {
    display: none
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the following css work fine for me thanks for your good point

.gwt-FileUpload {
    display: none
}

Comment: Hi! Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted (you can accept your own answer). Check out this article from help center: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers